# Request cURL with ESP8266

Tags: curl, arduino, esp8266, pushbullet

I am pretty new to programming (the ESP8266).
Right now I am putting code-pieces from different blogs together in order to receive(!) pushes (messages) from Pushbullet.
Sending already works great thanks to: 
[POST request on arduino with ESP8266 using WifiESP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354652/post-request-on-arduino-with-esp8266-using-wifiesp-library)

The cURL example from Pushbullet is:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data-binary '{"body":"Space Elevator, Mars Hyperloop, Space Model S (Model Space?)","title":"Space Travel Ideas","type":"note"}' \
     --request POST \
     https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
```

And the 'translation' to Arduino/ESP8266:

```cpp
String request = String("POST ") + url +" HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + push_bullet_host + "\r\n" +
                   "User-Agent: ESP8266/NodeMCU 0.9\r\n" +
                   "Accept: */*\r\n" +
                   "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                   "Content-Length: "+ body.length() +"\r\n" +
                   "Access-Token: "+ api_token +"\r\n\r\n" +
                   body;
secure_client.print(req);
```

So what I want to do now is requesting the latest messages from Pushbullet.
The example in cURL is:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>' \
     --data-urlencode active="true" \
     --data-urlencode modified_after="1.4e+09" \
     --get \
     https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
```

And my attempt to get it working is:

```cpp
  String request = String("GET ") + url +" HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + push_bullet_host + "\r\n" +
                   "User-Agent: ESP8266/NodeMCU 0.9\r\n" +
                   "Accept: */*\r\n" +
                   "active=\"true\"\r\n" +
                   "modified_after=\"1496508764\"\r\n" +
                   "Access-Token: "+ api_token +"\r\n\r\n";
  secure_client.print(req);
```

But all I receive is the following:

```
>>HTTP/1.1 200 OK>>
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1496515364>>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8>>
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 16384>>
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 16384>>
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: blablalba>>
Date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 18:05:06 GMT>>
Server: Google Frontend>>
Content-Length: 13626>>
```

I really appreciate any idea or solution.

Comment: how are you showing the server's response?  13k might be too much for ram, depending on what else is running on the ESP... Also, you can use the ESP8266HTTPClient examples instead of the nasty manual request packet building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active="true"` and `modified_after="1496508764"` are not valid headers.
You don't even want them in headers, since they are supposed to be query parameters.

You should append those parameters to the URL.

```cpp
String request = String("GET ") + url +"?active=true&modified_after=1.4e%2B09 HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + push_bullet_host + "\r\n" +
                 "User-Agent: ESP8266/NodeMCU 0.9\r\n" +
                 "Accept: */*\r\n" +
                 "Access-Token: "+ api_token +"\r\n\r\n";
```

You can see what exactly the `curl` command sends and receives, if you run it the `-v` or `--verbose` option:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>' \
     --data-urlencode active="true" \
     --data-urlencode modified_after="1.4e+09" \
     --get -v\
     https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
```

With this you would see:

```
* ... TLS stuff ...
> GET /v2/pushes?active=true&modified_after=1.4e%2B09 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.pushbullet.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Accept: */*
> Access-Token: <your_access_token_here>
>
< ... Response headers ...
```